# Will supercold flow extract heat from an ice cube?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, temperature, flow

Suppose you have an ice cube in a nonflowing liquid bath of *m*, where *m* is an element with a freezing temperature far below water (and whose temperature for this thought experiment is far below water’s freezing point).

Will the ice cube get *colder* if it is placed in a flowing bath of *m*? That is, will the direction of heat transfer occur from the ice cube *to* the infinitely flowing thermal sink?

Comment: This is basically what happens when you make ice cubes in a freezer. The freezer air  (usually about -20 degrees C) is colder than the water, so the water loses thermal energy and becomes ice (at 0 degrees C). The freezer air is still colder than the ice, so the ice then continues to lose thermal energy until it reaches the same temperature as the freezer air.

Answer (score 1):

You have not given the ice or liquid's temperatures. however heat always flows from a warmer to a colder environment. So if the ice cube is not as cold as the liquid, it will lose heat energy to the liquid, until they reach equilibrium.